# Share extension in swift *images*

Tags: xcode, swift, sharing

i'm trying to share an image in my xcode app. But having problems. All the good tuts i find on stackoverflow are in objective-c.  I followed this youtube tut over it, but with no luck.  In the video, he used this code. But when i tried to put a image in, and not sharing text like he did. I get an error.

```
@IBAction func share(sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img1.image!],       applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you post the Objective-C code so we can see if your swift code is correct.

Comment: show some more detail like what you tried.